# Azure Service Fabric StatelessService does not call OnCloseAsync

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a simple StatelessService and I want to knew when it is being closed down so I can perform some quick clean up. But it never seems to call OnCloseAsync.

When the service is running and I use the 'Restart' command on the running node via the Service Fabric Explorer, it removes the services and restarts the node. But it never calls the OnCloseAsync override, even though it is knowingly being closed down.

Nor does it signal the cancellationToken that is passed into the RunAsync method. So there is no indication that the service is being shutdown. Are there any circumstances when it does call OnCloseAsync, because I cannot see much point in it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder the reasoning behind issueing the restart command, what behavior do you expect? 
It does explain however the behavior you see. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-node-transition-apis) (Keep in mind that a restart is just a combined stop and start)

> Stopping a node puts it into a stopped state where it is not a member of the cluster and cannot host services, thus simulating a down node. This is useful for **injecting faults into the system** to test your application.

Now, if we take a look at [the lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle) we read this:

> After CloseAsync() finishes on each listener and RunAsync() also finishes, the service's StatelessService.OnCloseAsync() method is called, if present. OnCloseAsync is called when the stateless service instance is going to be **gracefully shut down.**

So, the basic problem is that you service is not gracefully shutdown. The restart command kills the process and no cancellation will be issued.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I did not realise that the Restart simulated a fault, but thought it was a graceful restart. My mistake. Is there a way to invoke a graceful restart of a service? I cannot find anything.

Comment: @PhilWright [This post](https://www.codit.eu/blog/restart-azure-service-fabric-service-with-code/) could be helpful.